# Switch to active cmd window for typing

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hotkeys

I've tried searching high and low for an answer by amending my title and reading questions before submission to no avail.

I'm learning bash shell through Ubuntu LTS via windows cmd terminal using Windows subsystem for Linux. However, I'm finding it very frustrating after using other active windows (such as chrome from referencing/tutorials) and having to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowKey(s)</kbd> every time I want to simply type in my terminal window.

I was wondering if there was a hotkey that exists to complete this process or how I could go about implementing a hotkey to automatically 'activate'/click-open inactive but current 'cmd.exe' window from any other active application as to begin typing after pressing the hotkey.

I have very little desire for a 'keep on top'-style solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see whether the following approach can help.

Windows 10 has a short cut to bring up a particular task bar item or minimize it, depending on its position on the "Taskbar".
Lets say I have "Snipping Tool" as the first iten in Taskbar. Then pressing "Windows" + 1 will maximize and minimize it regardless of which ever screen I am in. In the screenshot below, "Windows + 2" will do the smae for Chrome.

But for your purpose, I think you have to  add command prompt to your taskbar ( "Pin it to your taskbar by right clicking it on the task bar" ) .

Then limit the number of command prompts to just one for this to work without multiple keypress. That is, if you have two chrome windows, then to select the right one, you might have to press "Windows + 2" two times.

See whether this helps? Atleast it does not cost you a dime. Please upvote if you liked.

[image: illustration of Windows + 1, Windows + 2 below]